# Shorthand to speficy tests to run in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am aware of the --filter option to select the tests to run in dotnet core from the command line. For instance:

**dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName!~IntegrationTests**

What I am looking for is a way to do something like this?

**dotnet test --onlyUnitTests**

Where --onlyUnitTests would defined by the user in a settings file of some sort. Something like:

```
{
"onlyUnitTests": "--filter FullyQualifiedName\!~IntegrationTests"
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The closer a I got is adding a task in the file tasks.json

```
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run Unit Tests",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "--filter",      
                "FullyQualifiedName\!~IntegrationTests"],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
```

Now if I do Ctrl+Shift+P -> Run Tasks -> Run Unit Tests all my unit tests get executed.